# MySQL sequential number after where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have this table with column named `'Estudio'`, and another with `numDisco` and another one with the name `numID`. I want to first filter depending on the `'Estudio'` and then order by the `numDisco` and after that, in all the results that it drops set a sequential order starting from `1`. I have the query for order and filter

```
SELECT * FROM `archivo` WHERE `estudio` = "study" ORDER BY `archivo`.`numDisco` ASC
```

What I miss is the adding the sequential part just to those rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use a user variable that you increment.

```
UPDATE archivo
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @number := 0) AS x
SET numId = @number := @number + 1
WHERE estudio = "study"
ORDER BY numDisco ASC
```

Comment: thanks it's something like that, but i need that the sequential number is update in the column numID that i have

Comment: You mean you want to do an `UPDATE` statement instead of a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Yeah i mean i have 3 columns numID, numDisc, and Study, i want to filter by study, and when i filter i want to order ASC by num Disc, and based on that update the numID column sequentially.